# How to drop a relationship between two tables in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys, relationship

Hi i am a cs student learning DB at school. I am having a problem i made a test if it was possible to execute the relationship command more than one time and it got right (it added the same relationship more than one time) but I am not getting to delete these relationships , help me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Execute `SHOW CREATE TABLE dependent_table`. Look for excess constraint name. Drop it.

[Example DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f38f0f56f0dabc0b9e13106cbf2c087d)